# Facebook sign in not working

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, facebook

I can't sign in using Facebook. I get a "Data query failed error". Is there any chance you guys are using [Katana's Facebook OAuth provider](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/issues/38)?

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292989/facebook-data-query-failed-error-when-logging-in

Comment: Had/have the same problem. I chose to retrieve my password for the email account associated with Facebook login. It registered that I have no password and made me choose one. Though I still can't login with Facebook, I did login with my account.

Comment: Contrary to the advice given in the answer below, I would recommend running your browser in anonymous mode (incognito) to rule out any plugins, extensions, cookies, or other user data from being the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

We don't use that provider, no.

The root cause here was that v2.2 of the Facebook API fully expired on March 25, and v2.3 changed the format of the response from the `oauth/access_token` route. I've updated our code to handle the new format, so Facebook-based logins and signups are working again.

Answer (score -3):

Try with a different browser which does not have any plugins installed, this usually happens when you're using some plugins which interfere with FB content(add blocker ie).

Also make sure you are not behind a proxy or anonymous browsing.

Comment: I fail to see what anonymous browsing would have to do with this. Running a browser in anonymous browsing mode should be the fail safe way to see if it is a plugin, extension, cookie, or other user data that is causing the problem.